# How to write in new line in a file?

Tags: python

I need to create a program that saves people's information e.g. their name in a text file depending on the first letter of their surname so if their surname starts with a `K` it goes into `MyFile1`.

I need it to loop like I have done because it's an unknown number of people however I want each person to be written in a different line in the text file is there a way to do this.

The code at the bottom puts each separate information into a new line and I don't want that I want each different person to be in a new line.

```
MyFile1 = open("AL.txt", "wt")
MyFile2 = open("MZ.txt", "wt")
myListAL = ([])
myListMZ = ([])

while 1: 
    SurName = input("Enter your surname name.")
    if SurName[0] in ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"):
        Title = input("Enter your title.")
        myListAL.append(Title);
        FirstName = input("Enter your first name.")
        myListAL.append(FirstName);
        myListAL.append(SurName);
        Birthday = input("Enter birthdate in mm/dd/yyyy format:")
        myListAL.append(Birthday);
        Email = input("Enter your email.")
        myListAL.append(Email);
        PhoneNumber = input("Enter your phone number.")
        myListAL.append(PhoneNumber);
        for item in myListAL:
            MyFile1.write(item+"\n")

    elif SurName[0] in ("M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"):
        Title = input("Enter your title.")
        myListMZ.insert(Title);
        FirstName = input("Enter your first name.")
        myListMZ.append(FirstName);
        myListMZ.append(SurName);
        Birthday = input("Enter birthdate in mm/dd/yyyy format:")
        myListMZ.append(Birthday);
        Email = input("Enter your email.")
        myListMZ.append(Email);
        PhoneNumber = input("Enter your phone number.")
        myListMZ.append(PhoneNumber);
        line.write("\n")
        for item in myListMZ:
            MyFile2.write(line)

    elif SurName == "1":
        break


MyFile1.close()
MyFile2.close()
```

Comment: In your problem description you say "I want each person to be written in a different line" and also "I don't want that I want each different person to be in a new line". Please clarify which you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `join`.

When you have a list of items you can join them in a single string with.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(''.join(l))
```

produces

```
abc
```

You can not only use the empty string but also another string which will be used as separator

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(', '.join(l))
```

which now produces

```
a, b, c
```

In your examples (for example the first `write`)

```
MyFile1.write(','.join(MyListAL) + '\n')
```

If you happen to have something in the list which is not a string:

```
MyFile1.write(','.join(str(x) for x in MyListAL) + '\n')
```

(you can also use `map`, but a generator expression suffices)

Edit: adding the `map`:

```
MyFile1.write(','.join(map(str, MyListAL)) + '\n')
```

Comment: good answer. BTW, the gen expr doesn't need to be enclosed in parenthesis, just like any other expression: `', '.join(str(x) for x in MyListAL)`

Comment: This does do what I want to do so thank you but 1 more question it writes the first persons information on the first line and it then writes it in the second line as well as the second persons information if you know how to help me with this please reply

Comment: For the 2nd person you have to apply the same concept `MyFile2.write(','.join(str(x) for x in MyListMZ))`.  You are even already appending a `\n` to the list, so it will get appended to the end of the string

Comment: Thank you mementum so much it works and it does what i want

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would rather use a list of dictionaries, where a person with all its infos is a dictionary. Then you can convert it to a JSON string, which is a standard format for representing data. (Otherwise you need to define your own format, with delimiters between the items.)

So something like this:

```
import json # at the top of your script

# I would create a function to get the information from a person:
def get_person_input():
   person = {}
   person["surname"] = input("Surname: ")
   person["title"] = input("Title: ")
   person["email"] = input("Email: ")
   # TODO: do whatever you still want

   return person


# Later in the script when you want to write it to a file:
new_line = json.dumps( person )

myfile.write( new_line + "\n" )
```

Parsing a json is also very easy after all:

```
person = json.loads(current_line) # you can handle exception if you want to make sure, that it is a JSON format
```

You can use in your code for the decision in which array it should be written something like this:

```
SurName = input("Enter your surname name.")
if SurName[0] <= 'L':
    ...
else:
    ...
```

This will make your script more clear and robust.